# Gosund (tuya) SP1-C managment via telnet

Tags: web-sockets, lan

Can I turn on/off my electrical socket "Gosund SP1-C" from local network ? (via telnet, for example. Like it happened with Yeelight bulbs) I see that 80, 8080 and 5353 ports are opened but can't found any suggestion what command I can send to Gosand. (also, I failed with other tutorials, because this device don't use 'tuya app' and connect directly to Apple_cloud/homeKit/home_app and looks like can't be added/appear in 'tuya app'. And that why I can't get id/key that can be used for connecting to  Gosund via cli)

Comment: try using a web browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to manage my Gosund SP1-C outlet via `Homa Assistant` server and/or `Home Assistant` app.
I need:

1. pairing with Gosund SP1-C outlet via Home App and iPhone

   ```
    - this add my Gosund SP1-C outlet to 'local' network + iCloud (or HomeKit server)
   ```
2. remove Gosund SP1-C outlet from  Apple Home App

   ```
    - this remove my Gosund SP1-C from iCloud (or HomeKit server) but it should stay paired to the 'local' network
   ```
3. Now `Home Assistant` server able to found automatically `Gosund SP1-C` outlet  and you just need to pairing with it via code that located on QR label that attached to the `Gosund SP1-C` outlet (or it's box).

   ```
    - * both of them: `Home Assistant` server and `Gosund SP1-C` outlet need to be in same local network

    - * `HomeKit Controller` integration need to be installed already on `Home Assistant` server `http://ip_adress_of_your_server:8123/config/integrations`
   ```

After this steps you can able to control your HomeKit compatible-only `Gosund SP1-C` outlet via Android phone or browser via `Home Assistant` server web-page

https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/homekit_controller/